# Array Sort Comparator method always does a default comparison

Tags: java, sorting

I have  a class student - int age , int height and Name;

I have n objects of the student class and I try to sort then first by age , if there is a tie then by height , if there is a tie randomize name .

I have a class

```
class StudentComparator implements Comparator{

 public int compare(Object 1, Object2)
 {
    // Logic
 }

}
```

I have a main class

```
class StudentSorter {

  // Initialise student objects etc
  // Have an array of students: students[]              
    Array.Sort(students,new StudentComparator() )

   // print values

}
```

The problem I am facing is that Output does not resemble the logic I have in comparator method of the StudentComparator class. 
Logic is :

```
  if(Student1.age > student2.age)
    {
               return 1; 
    }    
    else if(Student1.age < student2.age)
    {
              return -1;
    }
     else 
     {
        if(Student1.height > Student2.height)
                    return 1; 
        else if(Student1.height < Student2.height)
                return -1;
             else 
                return 0;


      }
```

Input :
        
    15        6       John
    16        5       Sam
    17        6       Rooney

output: (no matter How I play around with logic or even comment it)

```
17        6       Rooney 
16        5       Sam
15        6       John
```

What might be the problem ?

Comment: You should show the given result and the wanted result as well as the logic you used.

Comment: Did you try using breakpoints or inserting print statements in your comparator method to see what's happening?

Comment: Show us the code that you really use. Instead of `Array.Sort` the proper name of the sorting method is `Arrays.sort`. You are also missing a semicolon at the end of that statement. And you should probably let the `StudentComparator` implement `Comparator<Student>`. This makes your code easier. And never do any random things in a comparator. This is forbidden by the specification of the `Comparator.compare` method. Read the documentation for details.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) 
{
    return s1.age == s2.age ? s1.height - s2.height : s1.age - s2.age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your students are ordered correctly. You just got the order direction wrong.

```
package so3898183;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

  @Override
  public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
    if (student1.age < student2.age)
      return -1; // if the first student is "smaller", return something small
    if (student1.age > student2.age)
      return 1; // if the first student is "larger", return something large

    if (student1.height < student2.height)
      return -1;
    if (student1.height > student2.height)
      return 1;

    return 0;
  }

}
```

Some remarks to the other solutions:

- Don't use the "trick" of subtracting `student1.age - student2.age` and examine the sign of the result. This will overflow for large numbers and may produce incorrect results.
- Keep your code as simple and readable as possible.
- Don't allocate extra objects (for example the `int[]` proposed in another response) when you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

If the first value is the age, as your sorted by age, the output is normal.

Comment: My problem is that even when I change the logic the out out remains same. What I mean by logic is suppose I do something like 
    if(Student1.age > student2.age)
    {
               return -1; 
    }    
    else if(Student1.age < student2.age)
    {
              return 1;
    }
     else 
     {
        if(Student1.height > Student2.height)
                    return -1; 
        else if(Student1.height < Student2.height)
                return 1;
             else 
                return 0;


      }

Comment: @Eternal Learner, did your recompile ? Are you sure that you're using the last version of your code ?

Comment: yeah I did recompile my code - and I get the same output every time I change logic

Comment: To verify this, put `if (true) return 0;` at the very beginning of the `compareTo` method. This should leave the order as-is. If it doesn't, step through your code with a debugger to find the problem.