# How to sort generic list by checking these 3 conditions

Tags: java, sorting

If we have a list as follow

```
Rollno name age address
====== ==== === =======
01      abc  11   pqr
02      stu  21   pqr
```

We are supposed to sort this list based on names. If the name of student is same then sort based on age and if age is also same then sort based on number.
I am stuck on how to sort names
The code that I have tried till is

```
public void sortData(List<Student> studentList) {
     String a1=null;
     String a2[] = null;
     int i=0;
    for (Iterator<Student> iter = list.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Student a = iter.next();
       System.out.println(a1 = a.getStudentName());

    }


    System.out.println(a2);
}
```

It is printing list of roll numbers but I am not getting how to sort them now.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Comparator`?

Comment: Can you just use `Collections.sort`?

Comment: no.. I am not familiar with java

Comment: I tried Collections.sort but it is not working.. may me i am not knowing right way to use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array Sort Comparator method always does a default comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898183/array-sort-comparator-method-always-does-a-default-comparison)

Comment: But then how can I check conditions i.e what if 2 persons are having same name

Comment: however It was also not working @ Madhan

Answer (score 1):

Use Comparable and Collections.sort():

```
public class TestClass {

@Test
public void testSort() {
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(  new Student( "two", "4", "street7" ) );
    list.add(  new Student( "two", "4", "street6" ) );
    list.add(  new Student( "one", "1", "street3" ) );
    list.add(  new Student( "two", "2", "street5" ) );



    Collections.sort( list );

    assertEquals( 
        "[Student [name=one, age=1, adress=street3], " +
        "Student [name=two, age=2, adress=street5], " +
        "Student [name=two, age=4, adress=street6], " +
        "Student [name=two, age=4, adress=street7]]", 
        list.toString() 
    );
}


public static class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    String name;
    String age;
    String adress;



    public Student( String name, String age, String adress ) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.adress = adress;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo( Student o ) {
        if ( o == null ) {
            return -1;
        }

        int compare = name.compareTo( o.name );
        if ( compare != 0 ) {
            return compare;
        }

        compare = age.compareTo( o.age );
        if ( compare != 0 ) {
            return compare;
        }

        return adress.compareTo( o.adress );
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( "Student [name=" );
        builder.append( name );
        builder.append( ", age=" );
        builder.append( age );
        builder.append( ", adress=" );
        builder.append( adress );
        builder.append( "]" );
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not working. I have already added elements in the list so list becomes as name rollno age and address. now I just want to sort the rows based on its name. If names are same then sort according to age and if age is also same then sort based on rollno