# How to sort generic list by checking these 3 conditions that is name age and rollno

Tags: java, sorting

Example I have list as:

```
rollno name age add
01      abc 12   abc  
02      pqr  13  srf
```

I want to sort the list based on names of student
If names are same, I have to sort based on age and if age are also same I want to sort it based on roll no

```
public void sortData(List<Student> studentList) {
    Student s1=null;
    Student s2=null;
    // Comparator<Student> StuNameComparator = new Comparator<Student>(); 

    String StudentName1 = s1.getStudentName().toUpperCase();
    String StudentName2 = s2.getStudentName().toUpperCase();

    //ascending order
    System.out.println(StudentName1.compareTo(StudentName2));

    //descending order
    //return StudentName2.compareTo(StudentName1);
}
```

Comment: you should clarify the structure of the class `Student` and how they should be compared - this question is rather unclear. You can sort a list using a `Comparator` this way: docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator) and `Comparator` is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort generic list by checking these 3 conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122387/how-to-sort-generic-list-by-checking-these-3-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Java SE 8 makes this easy, as you can define 3 [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s and chain them with one of the `thenComparing` methods.

Eg., something like this:

```
studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getName,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).
thenComparingInt(Student::getAge).
thenComparing(Student::getRollNo));
```

You might need to change the method names of Student etc.

Comment: but how to check condition whether names are same or not

Comment: @Sagar Equality can be checked with the equals method, but since you want to compare the Strings, you can use one of the compare methods of the String class.

Answer (score 0):

You have already asked same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122387/how-to-sort-generic-list-by-checking-these-3-conditions). Didn't that Answer your queries?
Please do some search before asking questions. And you should have used same question for further queries related to that question.

Well as an overview you can use the below Reference Code :-

```
/**
 * Adding students in ArrayList (rollNo, name, age)
 */
 ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();
    Student s1 = new Student(1, "abc",12);
    Student s2 = new Student(2,"def", 14);
    Student s3 = new Student(3, "ghi", 15);
    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);

    /**
     * Comparator by Name
     */
    public static Comparator<Student> getCompByName()
    {   
     Comparator comp = new Comparator<Student>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2)
         {
             return s1.name.compareTo(s2.name);
         }        
     };
     return comp;
    }

    /**
     * Comparator by Age
     */
    public static Comparator<Student> getCompByAge()
    {   
     Comparator comp = new Comparator<Student>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2)
         {
             return s1.age.compareTo(s2.age);
         }        
     };
     return comp;
    }

    /**
     * Comparator by Roll No.
     */
    public static Comparator<Student> getCompByRollNo()
    {   
     Comparator comp = new Comparator<Student>(){
         @Override
         public int compare(Student s1, Student s2)
         {
             return s1.rollNo.compareTo(s2.rollNo);
         }        
     };
     return comp;
    }

    /**
     * Comparison on basis of different criterias you can use
     */
    Collections.sort(students, Student.getCompByName());
    Collections.sort(students, Student.getCompByAge());
    Collections.sort(students, Student.getCompByRollNo());
```

For checking whether the List are same after every comparator, you can use :-

`listA.containsAll(listB) && listB.containsAll(listA)`

OR you can use Apache Common Utils `isEqualCollection()` for comparing 2 lists like :-

```
List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "b", "c");
List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("b", "c", "a", "b");
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(listA, listB)); // true

List<String> listC = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> listD = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "c");
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(listC, listD)); // false
```

Any extra logics which you want to have, implement in between.

Comment: @Sagar so any other query you have regarding the above ?

Comment: You sort the list 3 times. I don't think the OP expects eg. all names to be equal, but some might be, in which case the age should be regarded etc. So 3 times sorting and list equality checking doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @Puce I am not actually sorting the list but i am giving the refrence that he can actually sort the list based on different comparators he would have created ie for name, age and rollno & can check the lists in between that whether any change has happened or not